# Direct file access on tablet from LAN, as opposed to having to download files first

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, file-management, remote-access, lan

I am attempting to construct a LAN/WLAN to which computers, smartphones and tablet are connected. I would like to be able to access all these devices from from any device via some file manager and open these files locally 'on the fly' as opposed to having to download the files completely before I can open them.

I have done so with desktops and laptops on which either Windows or Ubuntu were installed. 'On the fly' file access works like a charm by means of Windows Explorer or Nautilus using Samba. I now want the same for smartphones and tablets.

I have attempted to do so by means of Samba again. But I do not know how to solve a few problems.

1) When using 'Samba Filesharing for Android' I can only seem to access data on the tablet/smartphone from the desktop/laptop, but not the other way around.
2) When using 'AndSMB' I can not directly open files on the other devices. I have to completely download them first.

I can't seem to find software for the Android smartphones and tablets that works as simple and effective as Windows Explorer or Nautilus, where you can open files locally without having to download them completely first, and do this from any device to any other device on the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up FTP server and/or Samba server on Android.

Example: ES File Explorer app provides such features.

Comment: Works great! phone/tablet->desktop/laptop file transfer with FTP and desktop/laptop->phone/tablet file transfer with Samba.